# cannot use java client to access rabbitmq in docker for windows

Tags: java, docker, rabbitmq

I have a docker container running rabbitmq. I can access web management(http://192.168.0.33:15672/) with an account test. But I want to use java client cant access and throw ACCESS_REFUSED exception.

my docker compose file

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.9-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    hostname: my-rabbit
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: admin
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: admin
```

project pom file

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
```

java code

```java
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.DeliverCallback;

public class Recv {

    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        factory.setPort(5672);
        factory.setUsername("test");
        factory.setPassword("test");
        factory.setVirtualHost("/");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

        DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
        };
        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });
    }
}
```

error exception

[AMQP Connection 192.168.0.33:5672] WARN com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler - An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Connection reset)
Exception in thread "main" com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.

Comment: Did you added the user 'test' with password 'test'? Can you connect from java using user admin and password admin?

Comment: @AndreiStoicescu I added user 'test' with password 'test'.cant connect from java using admin

Comment: Are you shure that "192.168.0.33" is your "localhost"?  Looks like you try to connect to different rebbit or with wrong login/password